# i want to read csv file and parse it to array but always fail

Tags: php, arrays, csv

my csv file link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Z58iD3By5wb2R2TnV0Rjc3Zzg/view

I already read many reference but I can not seperate my `csv` by "," (the delimiter not working properly). Is there a solution how could I get an array like this from that `csv` file:

```
`Array[0]=>
(

['username'] => Lexsa,

['date'] => 12/07/2017,

['retweet'] => null,

)`

`Array[1]=>
 (

 ['username'] => any,
 ['date'] => 12/07/2017,

 ['retweet'] => null
 )`



function csv_to_array($filename='', $delimiter=',')
{
if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
    return FALSE;

$header = NULL;
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(!$header)
            $header = $row;
        else
            $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
return $data;
}
```

I try to use many reference but the result is always like this the code wont split the line with `","` :

> Array ( [0] => Array    (["username","date","retweets","favorites","text","geo","mentions","hashtags","id","permalink"] => "Lexsa911","01/12/2016 0:05",0.0,0.0,"Kecelakaan - Kecelakaan Pesawat yang Melibatkan Klub-Klub Sepakbola http:// ht.ly/1IdL306EzDH",,,,"8,04E+17","https://twitter.com/Lexsa911/status/804008435020865536" )

Comment: This probably shouldn't be tagged as `python`.

Comment: ah sorry i'm new to stackoverflow but i like to search reference in here.  i will edit it.

Comment: First point is to see if you can alter how this file is generated as it seems to be full of ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get when I open your tes.csv with less or gedit:

```
"""username"",""date"",""retweets"",""favorites"",""text"",""geo"",""mentions"",""hashtags"",""id"",""permalink"""
"""Lexsa911"",""01/12/2016 0:05"",0.0,0.0,""Kecelakaan - Kecelakaan Pesawat yang Melibatkan Klub-Klub Sepakbola http:// ht.ly/1IdL306EzDH"",,,,""8,04E+17"",""https://twitter.com/Lexsa911/status/804008435020865536"""
"""Widya_Davy"",""01/12/2016 0:05"",0.0,0.0,""Kecelakaan - Kecelakaan Pesawat yang Melibatkan Klub-Klub Sepakbola http:// ow.ly/h1Eh306EzHk"",,,,""8,04E+17"",""https://twitter.com/Widya_Davy/status/804008434588876803"""
"""redaksi18"",""01/12/2016 0:05"",0.0,0.0,""Klub Brasil Korban Kecelakaan Pesawat Didaulat Jadi Juara http:// beritanusa.com/index.php?opti on=com_content&view=article&id=39769:klub-brasil-korban-kecelakaan-pesawat-didaulat-jadi-juara&catid=43:liga-lain&Itemid=112 … pic.twitter.com/1K7OlZSX83"",,,,""8,04E+17"",""https://twitter.com/redaksi18/status/804008416188338176"""
"""JustinBiermen"",""01/12/2016 0:06"",0.0,0.0,""Video LUCU Kecelakaan Yg Sangat Koplak http://www. youtube.com/watch?v=pQFOY7 AdXck …"",,,,""8,04E+17"",""https://twitter.com/JustinBiermen/status/804008714738880512"""
```

So the issue is not the delimiter, but rather the enclosure. As you can see, each line is wrapped in quotes. So the entire line is considered to be a *single* column.

I suggest to fix the csv, e.g. remove the quotes until a row looks like

```
"username","date","retweets","favorites","text","geo","mentions","hashtags","id","permalink"
```

If you cannot do that for some reason, preprocess the csv to clean it up:

```
print_r(
    array_map(
        function($line) {
            $single_quoted_line = str_replace(['"""', '""'], '"', $line);
            return str_getcsv($single_quoted_line);
        },
        file("tes.csv")
    )
);
```

Comment: ah i see . i'll check it because this csv is generated from tweepy and i use rapid miner to clean the data and export it as csv again. that file is just few row. thanks i'll try it

Comment: it works with the original file with delimiter ";". thanks but i need to do some research about the file generated from rapid miner csv file....

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV is formatted with each field enclosed in two `"` characters to the left and right, and then each line is also enclosed within a single `"` character to the left and right. As a result, each line in your CSV is read in as a `string`. That's why your result is an associative array with the entire header as a single `string` as the key, and the value associated with the key is also an entire line as a single `string`.

Try reformatting your CSV so each field is enclosed to the left and right in a single `"` character, and remove the additional `"` characters from the beginning and end of each line. Your code should then produce your expected results.

If you aren't able to control the format of the CSV, you'll need to do some sanitation before parsing with `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: ah i see . i'll check it because this csv is generated from tweepy and i use rapid miner to clean the data and export it as csv again. that file is just few row. thanks i'll try it